# Tweet text from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I want to take some text from the HTML page and tweet it out.

Here is my HTML page -

```js
function change() {
  quotes = ["Naam toh suna hi hoga", "Mogambo Khush Hua", "Kitne aadmi the?"];
  auth = ["Raj", "Mogambo", "Gabbar"];
  min = 0;
  max = 3;
  num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  q = quotes[num]
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[num];
  document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = auth[num];
  if (num == 0) {
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color = 'white';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
  if (num == 1) {
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color = 'black';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    document.getElementById("another").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("tweet").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
  if (num == 2) {
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color = 'white';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }

}

function twitter() {
  text = document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML;
  // document.getElementById('tw').innerHTML = text;

  $('.twitter-button').attr("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + text);
};
```

```html
<body id='bod'>
  <h1>Quotes</h1>
  <div class='text'>
    <p id='quote'>You're fired!</p>
    <br>
    <p id='author'>Vince McMahon</p>

    <button id='another' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='change()'>Another Quote</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a class="twitter-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" target="_blank">
      <button type="button" onclick='twitter()' class="btn btn-primary" id='tw'>Tweet!</button>
    </a>
```

Whenever I click on the tweet button, there is no text on the twitter page. Just a blank box.

Link to Codepen - https://codepen.io/pranavgoel25/pen/ZybNRv?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweeked a code bit:

```
    var quotes = ["Naam toh suna hi hoga","Mogambo Khush Hua","Kitne aadmi the?"];

function change(){   
  auth = ["Raj","Mogambo","Gabbar"];
  min = 0;
  max = 3;
  num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  q = quotes[num]
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[num];
  document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = auth[num];
  document.getElementById('twitterBtn').setAttribute("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=twee' + quotes[num]);
  if (num == 0){
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color='white';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor='green';
  document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor='green';
  }
  if (num == 1){
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color='black';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    document.getElementById("another").style.color='black';
    document.getElementById("tweet").style.color='black';
  document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor='yellow';
  }
  if (num == 2){
    document.getElementById("bod").style.color='white';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById("another").style.backgroundColor='blue';
  document.getElementById("tweet").style.backgroundColor='blue';
  }  

}

window.onload = function(){  
  document.getElementById('twitterBtn').setAttribute("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=twee' + quotes[0]);
}
```

Working Demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZjQBe?editors=1010